# What is a "bi-infinite matrix"?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a wavelet analysis book. In one section there is a term "bi-infinite matrix". I have searched a lot but has not found a good definition. So can anyone tell me, in concise, what's the definition of "bi-infinite matrix"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Infinite number of rows and infinite number of columns?

Comment: A sequence labelled by the integers (instead of just the natural numbers) is sometimes called a bi-infinite sequence (it has infinitely many entries in both the positive and negative directions). So perhaps a bi-infinite matrix is one whose elements are labelled by integers. That is, it is of the form $(a_{mn})$ where $m, n \in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Al already mentioned, a bi-infinte matrix may just refer to an structure like $(a_{nm})_{n,m\in\mathbb{Z}}$. However, recalling that matrices are most often representations of linear maps between finite dimensional vector space, a bi-infinite matrix may also refer to a representation of an operator that maps between two vector spaces of bi-infinite sequences, e.g. between two spaces of the form 
$$
\ell^p(\mathbb{Z}) = \Big\{(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\ :\ \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |a_k|^p<\infty\Big\}
$$
for some values $1\leq p <\infty$.